# Logging in over and over again. How to fix this?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, login-screen, awesome

Ok, I messed up. I installed ubuntu 11.10, installed `awesome wm` and [removed](http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-remove-unity-and.html) `unity`, to have something to fall back on, I also installed `gnome-session-fallback`.

I was messing around and did the following, because the [awesome wiki](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome) told me to:

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop False
# Still disable the buggy Nautilus desktop thing
gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager awesome
# sets awesome as wm
```

Now here's what's wrong: I can start up decently, and then I get into a login window (that of `gnome-session-fallback`). I enter my username, select the preferred window manager (`awesome` in my case) and enter my password. It accepts these, but then hold for a second and just opens the login window again, in effect preventing me from actually logging in.

I also tried `gconftool-2 --unset` (from the `tty`) on these settings, but that didn't work either.

What can I do to revert the `gconftool-2` settings to something that should work? I tried `apt-get purging` `gnome-session-fallback` and `lightdm`, and then installing them again, but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @pl1nk: yes I threw out gnome, ... In fact I threw out ubuntu and switched to Arch, which has never let me down since.

Answer (score 0):

Try these (after reinstalling gnome-session-fallback):

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop True
gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager /usr/bin/metacity
```