# Starting awesome-wm when using startx?

Tags: xorg, console, awesome

I uninstalled `gnome-session-fallback` and `gdm`, when I start the machine, it boots in console mode. I can log in normally.

Using `startx` starts up the remnants of GNOME that are still on my machine (a desktop with icons and hardly any UI).

How could I set my `Xorg` settings so that `awesome` is started when I use `startx`?

Answer (score 6):

Create a file named `.xinitrc` in your home directory, with this contents:

```
awesome
```

The `.xinitrc` file lists commands that are executed by [startx](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/startx) in order to set up the X11 session/desktop.
You may for instance add other programs to be started (just append a `&` after the program invocation so that the shell does not wait for their termination before continuing).

The `startx` session exits when the last command from `.xinitrc` finishes, so be sure that the invocation of `awesome` is the last thing you do in that script.

Comment: I have fixed this (I hope). The other question was open and this one is now unrelated to it. Please move your now deleted question in to the first question and I will make sure that it will get at least the up vote I had given it before. Sorry, can't move answers without making things worst.

Comment: @BrunoPereira Thanks! I have re-posted my old answer to the [Logging in over and over again](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112832/logging-in-over-and-over-again-how-to-fix-this) question

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple window managers and desktop environments, you can run:

```
startx awesome
```

in a new virtual terminal.

Comment: In my case this only opens awesome kinda ... it shows up, the cursor moves correctly, I can type inside the initially open terminal... but nothing happens, and I can't click anything, until I stop it again with ctrl+C, which kills awesome. Probably an issue on my side and not with this answer though.